# Outlook Unread Messages System Tray Envelope Icon Not Showing when System Tray is minimized

Tags: windows-xp, microsoft-outlook, notification-area

My coworker wants to see a little "new mail" letter icon whenever he has new mail in Outlook.

I went to

> Tools -> Options -> Preferences -> E-mail Options -> Advanced E-mail
>   Options -> Show an envelope icon in the notification area

to turn it on, but it doesn't show the "new mail" whenever receiving new mail while the program is minimized to system tray.

This is on Windows XP btw

Comment: What version of Outlook?

Comment: If memory serves right it is outlook 2007

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that when you say "...the system tray is minimized" you mean that you have "Hide inactive icons" turned on, I think you want:

> (right-click Taskbar) -> Properties -> Customize (next to "Hide inactive icons")
>
> Find the new mail icon (possibly in "Past Items") and change the behaviour to "Always Show".

Comment: Sorry I mean every time the program is minimized to system tray

Comment: I'm not completely satisfied with this answer but since it is the best I'm going to award it to this post :)

Answer (score 0):

if you have already tried enabling the notification in the system tray, make sure the Outlook settings are correct by selecting the check box next to "show envelope in the system tray". To do this

1. open outlook
2. select actions
3. options
4. email options
5. advanced email options
6. check "show envelope icon in notification area"